# Handling manufacturer mergers

Tags: database-design

Is there a standard pattern for linking products to manufacturers, when we want to capture the fact that manufacturers are interacting with each other over time (mergers, takeovers, etc)?

In our industry, company A makes product 1, and many people refer to that product with a token like "A-1" when talking about it or trying to look up detailed performance and physical characteristics of that product in our database.

If company B purchases A, we still want to be able to allow people to use a token like "A-1" to look up the performance data of that product, even though the owning company is now B. A new user meanwhile can look at the records and understand that company A made the product and is the former owner, while company B is now the "real" owner.

Is it viable to model this with two manufacturer foreign keys, and a version column that would increment when the manufacturer relationship changes? The version column would be used to allow the older "A owns 1" row to remain in the table for existing records that linked to it at the time A owned 1 before being bought out by B.

[image]

Comment: Is the history meant to only capture manufacturer changes or changes of products as well? In other word, if a products characteristics change (in the real world) should the changes be reflected in all the rows for a product or only the one with the current manufacturer?

Comment: Are we to assume that a part can only have one manufacturer or supplier?  I am thinking this may be addressed by creating history tables at different levels in the database but need more clarification of the existing structure.

Comment: A product can have one "owner," which could also be the manufacturer, or a "published" manufacturer that's different from the "owner." This would handle the case where company B buys A and now owns product but want's to keep producing product under subsidiary A. No other manufacturer relationships than that (e.g. can't have more than one owner or published manufacturer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a join table with a date of validity

```
product_id           refernjces product(id),
manufacturer_id      references manufacturere(id),
start_date           not null default CURRENT_DATE
end_date
```

you'll probably need several indices depending on what reports you want from the database.

Comment: Wouldn't this also need a "relationship_type" column to denote "owner" vs. "published manufacturer" vs. perhaps other types that arise in future? I guess this approach would probably be good for handling unknown future relationships.

Comment: if you need to track those things make a new join table.. (I'm not a fan of anything approaching EAV)

Comment: (typo ... see modified entry below)

Comment: But isn't "owner" vs. "published manuf" a quality of the first join table you suggested? What two tables are you thinking would be joined by this second join table? Thanks for any clarification, Jasen!

Comment: potentially the same two tables.

Comment: Ok. My assumption is that a "type" column could handle the owner vs. published manufacturer distinction. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: a type column is likely to hurt more than it helps in the long run. try to stick to third normal form

Comment: Isn't a column "relationship_type" consistent with 3rd normal form, in that it's providing a fact about the relationship between the manufacturer and product at a point in time (a potential compound primary key), not the manufacturer itself?

Comment: That approach puts several different meanings on the manufacturer id column

Comment: Yes, that's what we need. We need to be able to say "as of today, this product is manufactured by company X, and is owned by company Y" ... I think the confusing thing is the `manufacturer_id` column should probably be `company_id`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I might approach this design... by adding an ID for the original manufacturer at the Product level, then storing the details in a history table.

The history table would allow for Manufacturer IDs (or other details) to change over time to be stored without a need for version numbers.

### Product table

Product_ID
Product_Name
Orig_Mfgr_ID

### Product History table

Product_ID
ProductHistory_ID
Orig_Mfgr_ID
Mfgr_StartDate
Mfgr_EndDate
CreateDate

I would then create a view or function to pull the most recent/current manufacturer based on the purchase date of the product, rather than storing this information in the Product table itself.

Comment: Yes, ok. I think this is similar to the idea directly above by @Jasen. I guess this works as long as the history table can have contemporaneous entries to represent two current relationships: an "owner" manufacturing company and a "published manufacturer." (Use case above where B buys A but wants to keep using A as subsidiary to make product.)